# Toggle fzf.vim if already open

Tags: buffers, functions, plugin-fzf

I am trying to write a vim function to toggle the `fzf` window if it is already open using [`fzf.vim`](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim).

The use case is if I am in the `:Buffers` view and I want to change to the `:Files` view if I try to execute `:Files` before closing `:Buffers` then `fzf.vim` complains.

The code is as below:

```
function FzfRunning()
    let buffers = filter(range(1, bufnr('$')), 'bufname(v:val) =~# ";#FZF"')
    for i in buffers
        " Delete buffer by ID
        execute "bw!" . i
    endfor
endfunction

command! -nargs=* ToggleFiles call FzfRunning| Files
command! -nargs=* ToggleBuffers call FzfRunning| Buffers
```

This works except for the fact that the `fzf` buffer loses focus. I would like it to focus the `fzf` buffer when `ToggleFiles` or `ToggleBuffers` is called.

Comment: Something like `execute 'bdelete ' . bufname(';#FZF')`? (maybe you'll have to change `;#FZF` to the actual name of a fzf buffer)

Comment: `:function!` – analogously to `:command!` – enables you to overwrite an existing function definition of the same name without restarting vim.  Useful during vimscript dev/ debugging, as you seem to be doing.

Comment: You selected the [tag:global-command] tag.  That refers specifically to the `:g` (alias `:global`) command, thus is not applicable here.  (I submitted an edit to remove it.)

Comment: `command!` ***`-nargs=*`*** only makes sense if you use the arguments (if I'm not mistaken); in this case probably by passing them on: `command! -nargs=* ToggleFiles call FzfRunning() | Files <args>`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with adding `sleep`

```
function FzfRunning()
  let buffers = filter(range(1, bufnr('$')), 'bufname(v:val) =~# ";#FZF"')
  for i in buffers
    " Delete buffer by ID
    execute 'bw! ' . i
  endfor
  " we need to sleep here so fzf will be focused properly
  sleep 10m
endfunction
```